# get pipeline specific run ID

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i am working on azure rest api to get unit test count for specific project, and i found this api inside documents

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=6.0
```

this gives me all the run id by which i can my unit test results by using another api call
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runid}/results?api-version=6.1-preview.6`
but my problem is my project has multiple test pipeline, is there any way i get pipeline specific run id via passing pipeline id ?

Comment: Please check if the several answers below can resolve your issue, if yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can try to filter the results returned by the API. For example, when we use [Get a list of test runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.3`

We can find build id in the result.

[image]

- We can add buildIds when using [queue test runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API:

  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}&buildIds={buildIds}&api-version=6.1-preview.3`

We can find build id and definition id from the result.
[image]

Comment: i have already find the solution but it's exactly same which you suggested here, Thanks

Comment: @RajnishTyagi Glad to hear that! Appreciate for [marking it as an snswer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thank you.

Comment: can't do it due to low reputation score :(

Comment: @RajnishTyagi Marking answers does not require reputation.  You can refer to [this ticket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thank you.

Comment: Quite Helpful! Thx you! Doing the same thing with curl calls via ADO script.

Comment: how to get build id?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Following are the parameters that you need to specify:

[image]

You will get detailed info on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: Hi @Rajnish : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !